# flask-sqlalchemy: how to define the 'comment' model (multi foreign keys referring to the same table)?

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a video sharing site, where users can comment under a video, or comment to someone else's comment. Here's my simplified user model and comment model:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id              = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username        = db.Column(db.String(MAX_USERNAME), unique=True)
    comments        = db.relationship('Comment', backref='replier', lazy='dynamic')
    replied         = db.relationship('Comment', backref='repliee', lazy='dynamic')

class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id              = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content         = db.Column(db.Text)
    replier_id      = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), index=True)
    repliee_id      = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), index=True)
    video_id        = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('videos.id'), index=True)
```

It prompts me with error:

> Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.comments - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table

Anybody can help? New to flask and sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `comments` and `replied` relationships don't know which foreign key column on `Comment` to use, since both `replier_id` and `repliee_id` refer to `users.id`.

So add the appropriate `foreign_keys` arguments to `comments` and `replied`:

```py
comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref='replier', lazy='dynamic', foreign_keys='[Comment.replier_id]')
replied = db.relationship('Comment', backref='repliee', lazy='dynamic', foreign_keys='[Comment.repliee_id]')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Another question about sqlalchemy's design: why in a `relationship`, the class to be related with uses string, as in my example the `'Comment'`, but in `foreign_keys`, it uses direct reference: `Comment.replier_id` or `Comment.repliee_id`? I don't know if it is intended this way or if it is just arbitrarily designed this way.

Comment: It will accept either string or reference in both cases. With string, the model being referred to does not have to be defined at that point. I suppose it would be better to keep it consistent.